# XSLT: element that has no attributes and no children transform to parent attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xls

The structure, names, values of the given .xml files is unknown.

For every not-root element that has simple structure(has no child-nodes, has no attributes, BUT has text and is not empty) transform it into parent's attribute.

I have .xml file:

```
<list>
   <worker>
      <name atr="ss">val1</name>
   </worker>
   <worker>
      <make1>val2</make1>
   </worker>
   <worker>
      <name>
        <make2>val3</make2>
      </name>
   </worker>
   <worker>
      <name>
        <doo atr="ss1">val4</doo>
        <make3></make3>
      </name>
   </worker>
</list>
```

And I want to get this:

```
<list>
   <worker>
      <name atr="ss">val1</name>
   </worker>
   <worker make1="val2"/>
   <worker>
      <name make2="val3"/>
   </worker>
   <worker>
      <name>
        <doo atr="ss1">val4</doo>
        <make3/>
      </name>
   </worker>
</list>
```

Here is my .xsl for now (doesn't work correctly):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//*[not(*|@*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your code

You've got two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(@*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Your output produces `<worker><make1 make1="val2"/></worker>` instead of `<worker make1="val2"/>`.  This is because the outer `<worker>` element is processed by the top template, which just copies it and then passes the child along, which gets processed by the bottom template.

### A working approach

The following works for me, and uses only one template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <!-- Capture any child elements with no attributes and no children. -->
            <xsl:for-each select="*[not(@*) and not(*)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- Apply templates to **only** those children that have either
                attributes or children of their own, and to text. -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@* or *]|text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key difference: any element that meets your criteria -- has no child elements, has no attributes, only has text -- does **not** get processed by applying a template, and instead it gets processed within that `for-each` loop.  So we never wind up with a copy of that element.

#### Update

We now have a clarified provision that empty elements that lack even text are to be kept as independent elements.  So for a snippet like the following, with the empty `EXTRA` element:

```
<worker>
    <name>
        <doo atr="ss1">val4</doo>
        <make3>val4</make3>
        <EXTRA></EXTRA>
    </name>
</worker>
```

... we would want output like:

```
<worker>
    <name make3="val4">
        <doo atr="ss1">val4</doo>
        <EXTRA/>
    </name>
</worker>
```

... which maintains `EXTRA` as an independent element, and only attribute-ifies the `make3` element.

This XSL should do the trick.  This reworks the `select` statements from the code above.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <!-- Capture any child elements with no attributes and no children,
            and that also have text. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="*[not(@*) and not(*) and text()]">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- Apply templates to **only** those children that have no text, or
            that have attributes or children of their own, and also apply to text. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@* or * or not(text())] | text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

**XSL 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*|@*)]" mode="attribute"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*|@*] | text()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="attribute">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Keep in mind that attributes must be created before child elements.

---

### Added in response to change in requirements:

At some point, the amount of conditions becomes sufficient to justify writing them only once, and avoid duplicating them in the negative by defining the "other" node-set in terms of set-difference (i.e. non-intersection):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="my-set" select="*[text() and not(*|@*)]" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$my-set" mode="attribute"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(count(.|$my-set) = count($my-set)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="attribute">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Using Saxon-HE 9.6.0.7, the code above appears to strip text content.  So instead of `<name atr="ss">val1</name>`, we get `<name atr="ss"/>`.  This doesn't match what the OP posted for desired output XML.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi You're right, thanks for the catch. I believe it's fixed now.

Comment: Cheers.  :)  +1 too for the comment about attributes and the order of processing.