# elements to attribute with custom conditions ignoring few elements

Tags: java, xml, xslt

while converting the element to attributes I am checking the name of parent element whether it present in element which we tried to convert as attribute.

Example like planet_name is the element and it contains the parent element (planet) so need to covert this as attribute otherwise as-is and also want to exclude few elements like parent_element and planet_number.

I wrote the xslt but its not working can any one please help on this?. Thanks in advance.

Sample XML Example:

```
<world>
            <planet>
               <planet_name>solaris</planet_name>
               <planet_number>23</planet_number>
               <test>value1</test>
               <parent>
                   <test>test1</test>
                   <parent_element>test</parent_element>
               </parent>
             </planet>
</world>
```

Expected Output:

```
<world>
            <planet planet_name="solaris">
                <planet_number>23</plante_number>
                 <parent>
                   <test>test1</test>
                   <parent_element>test</parent_element>
               </parent>
               <test>value1</test>
             </planet>
</world>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(), name(current()))]" mode="attr"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(starts-with(name(), name(current())))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="attr">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XSLT looks very generic (which is good!), but what are the precise rules for excluding elements? Or do you actually want the names of the elements you need excluded to be hard-coded in the XSLT? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any specific rules to exclude elements but I have list of elements to exclude?. I have the list and want to hard code in xslt to skip the elements

Comment: Martin Honnen gave you a good answer, but see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44554260/3016153

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(), name(current()))]" mode="attr"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(), name(current())) and not(name() = 'planet_number' or name() = 'parent_element')]" mode="attr"/>
```

and the other `apply-templates` to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(starts-with(name(), name(current()))) or name() ='planet_number' or name() = 'parent_element']"/>
```

should do: http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zCW.